# Aligning Two Seperate text in left and making a iconbutton in full right centering tthe two text Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have two seperate text in an container and I need a icon to come right to this text and need to be center aligned to both this text. I dont know how to make this happen. Am sorry If this question is already asked but I can't that question. Help me to understand how that works.

[image]

You can see in the buttom i have both price text and an cart icon centered to them in right. How can I achieve this please help me.

I will share the code for the rest . If you can make the code better that will help too...

```
Container(
            width: 430,
            height: 350,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black45),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 40),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          SizedBox(width: 20),
                          Text("Blue Star 1.5 ton 5 star inverter AC",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                          ),)
                        ],
                      ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: const [
                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Text("Blue Star",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                Image.asset("assets/air_conditioner.png",
                  height:180,
                width: 340,),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(width: 30,),
                    const Text("₹54,000 (10% OFF)",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                    ),),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){},
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart))
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 05),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(width: 35),
                    const Text("₹60,000",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                        fontSize: 14
                      )),
                  ],
                )
            ],
                )
            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've edited your code:

```
Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black45),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20,vertical: 30),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  const Text("Blue Star 1.5 ton 5 star inverter AC",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                    ),),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  const Text("Blue Star",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Center(
                    child: Image.asset("assets/air_conditioner.png",
                      height:180,
                      width: 340,),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          Text("₹54,000 (10% OFF)",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.redAccent,
                                fontSize: 17,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                            ),),
                          Text("₹60,000",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                                  fontSize: 14
                              )),
                        ],
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                          onPressed: (){},
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart))
                    ],
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            )
        )
```

some notes:

1. try to use padding instead of `SizedBox` for setting padding sides. because SizedBox is using for setting spaces between something ...
2. crossAxisAlignment default is center if you want to make it start you should use `CrossAxisAlignment.start`
3. do not use static sizes for Container if it is not force let it fill itself
4. mainAxisSize default is max but here you should use `MainAxisSize.min` to let it use its real size of the widget.
   if you had any questions i'm here.
   happy coding...

Comment: Thank you It works... I learnt many things by the notes

Comment: you're welcome, i'm here if you had any questions. by the way, we can connect on linkedin if you had any questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
            width: 430,
            height: 350,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black45),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 40),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: const [
                          SizedBox(width: 20),
                          Text("Blue Star 1.5 ton 5 star inverter AC",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                          ),)
                        ],
                      ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: const [
                      SizedBox(width: 20),
                      Text("Blue Star",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
                Image.asset("assets/air_conditioner.png",
                  height:180,
                width: 340,),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(width: 30,),
                    const Text("₹54,000 (10% OFF)",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500
                    ),),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){},
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart))
                  ],
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 05),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(width: 35),
                    const Text("₹60,000",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough,
                        fontSize: 14
                      )),
                      IconButton(
                        onPressed: (){},
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart))
                  ],
                ),
            ]),
            ),
```

Comment: This has two icons right